# Как записать файл в /system/ в android?

Tags: android, java

Выполняю следующий код:

```
File myF = new File("/system/", "build.prop1");
try {
    FileReader fRd = new FileReader(myF);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fRd);
    String str;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(str + "\n");
    }
    fRd.close();
    myEdit.setText(buffer.toString());
    globalbuffer = buffer;
    reader.close();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Все отлично читается, но когда выполняю вот этот код,

```
File myFNew = new File("/system/","build.prop1.baktw");
File myF1 = new File("/system/","build.prop1q");

try
{
    myF1.renameTo(myFNew);
    myF1.delete();
    myF1.createNewFile();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + myF1.createNewFile(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try 
    {
        FileWriter fWr = new FileWriter(myF1);                   
        fWr.write(globalbuffer.toString());
        fWr.flush();
        fWr.close();      
    }
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

catch (Exception e1) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

У меня все дело стопорится на

```
myF1.createNewFile();
```

Типа у меня недостаточно прав на запись... для доступа использую roottools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо дать рут права Java машинке, а потом выполнить `mount` на /system

```
String command="mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system"; //точный маунт зависит от реализации
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()); 
os.write(command);
os.flush();         
os.close();
```

Comment: хорошо, а куда указать файл для записи? как я понял в OutputStreamWriter нету ссылки на файл